# Make ImageButton in GridView invisible

Tags: android, gridview

I need to know how to access an individual element in a GridView so I can set it's visibility. *Look for the all caps comment in the MovementSelectionFragment.* Thanks

```
public class MovementSelectionFragment extends Fragment{
private static final int REQUEST_NEW_MOVEMENT = 0;

private GridView mGridView;
private ArrayList<Integer> movements = new ArrayList<Integer>();
/*
 * This array allows the user to select multiple workouts at once. 
 * It doesn't need to be reinstantiated every time the user backs up
 * to this view.
 */

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

 @Override 
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movement_selection, parent, false);

    mGridView = (GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    mGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(v.getContext()));

    //*************************************************************//
    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                long id) {

            // Sending image id to WODListActivity
            Intent movementIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                    WODListActivity.class);
            movements.add(position); // Add the position to the movements
                                        // array.
            // show contents of integer array that holds the positions of
            // the movements selected so far (use this to set button
            // visibility)
            for (int i = 0; i < movements.size(); i++) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),
                        Integer.toString(movements.get(i)),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // THIS KILLS THE ENTIRE VIEW (OBV)
                // I NEED IT TO ONLY KILL THE SELECTED ELEMENT
                mGridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            movementIntent.putExtra(WODListFragment.NEW_MOVE_ADDED,
                    movements);
            startActivityForResult(movementIntent, REQUEST_NEW_MOVEMENT);
        }

    });//*************************************************************//

    return v;
 } 

 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK){ 
         return;
     }
 }
```

}

**This is the ImageAdapter class I am using**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.push_up_icon, R.drawable.pull_up_icon,
        R.drawable.burpees, R.drawable.air_squats,
        R.drawable.hspu_icon, R.drawable.mtn_climbers,
        R.drawable.run_icon, R.drawable.jump_rope,
        R.drawable.lunges, R.drawable.box_jumps,    
};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

    imageView.setTag(new Integer(position));

    return imageView;
}
```

}

Maybe something needs to be modified in getView()?

Comment: yes exactly in the getview method the position variable tells you which grid position you are currently working and in that method you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
mGridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

with...

```
v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```